# Could not obtain information about windows nt group/user sql server error

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I migrated my Access Backend to SQL Server using SQL Server Migration Assistant. During the Installation of SQL Server I made sure that my windows account was set up as the sys admin. When I view my login "office/dave" I can see that I have sys admin server role. I have access to every objects in the SQL Backend when I am browsing through SSMS but I could not access the database diagrams.

I did fix this issue by changing the database owner to [sa] from "office/dave" in the database properties and this let me access the database diagram but I do not understand why this fixed the problem.

I was connected as sys admin and database owner. Why is this fix needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help someone in the future. This error can occur which did for me because I was logged in as Domain User and was not connected to local User. This error can be fixed by changing the database owner to [sa] account.